# Getting started with Google Analytics API missing a package or wrong version of the package?

Tags: python, google-analytics-api

I downloaded the sample from getting started with Google Analytics API.

When I try to run it:

I get the following error:

> pkg_resources.ContextualVersionConflict: (protobuf 3.0.0 (/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages), Requirement.parse('protobuf>=3.12.0'), {'google-api-core'})

What could be wrong?

I am not sure how to fix this. From what I understand protobuy version needs to be 3.12.0 while that is not present?

Answer (score 1):

As per the source code of latest Google API Core [release](https://github.com/googleapis/python-api-core/blob/v1.21.0/setup.py#L33) it requires `"protobuf >= 3.12.0",`.  So please do a install of [protobuf 3.12.0](https://pypi.org/project/protobuf/3.12.0/) or the latest one `pip install protobuf`.

Answer (score 1):

The error message is reporting a mismatch between the version of protocol buffers installed in your OS and the more recent version required by the GA API.

You could see if your OS's package manager can provide a more recent version of protocol buffers.

You could upgrade the OS's version using pip, but this is not a good idea; other packages may depend on the current version, and upgrading via pip will confuse the package manager.

I would suggest creating a [virtual environment](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html#venv-def) and installing protocol buffers and the GA API there.

```sh
python -m venv /path/to/myenv
```

Activate the virtual environment:

```sh
source /path/to/venv/bin/activate
```

Installed the packages in the virtual environment's Python.

```sh
pip install protobuf
pip install <name-of-google-analytics-api-package>
```

The virtual environment may be deactivated like this:

```sh
source /path/to/venv/bin/decativate
```

Comment: Tried it, I managed to install the protobuf v3.12.xx but still gettiing the same error. Its in virtual env, the virtual env is active. Can't understand why it still sees the 3.0.0 version.

Comment: My bad - the venv should be activated before installing the packages - I've edited the steps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this and reboot.

```
pip install protobuf==3.12.0
```